# What kind of copy is slice operation a[:]?

Tags: python

I leave python for a while and now I'm preparing for interviews. When I was reviewing some basics I found this:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(3)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]

>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a[:] = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]

>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b.append(3)   # /a[:].append(3)
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

As I understand it, in the second case a[:] acts as a shallow copy while in the third it is a deep copy. Can anyone help me with this basic concept, thanks beforehand.

Comment: Define what you mean by "shallow" and "deep" copy here…?

Comment: The third is not a deep copy, although it doesn't matter in this case since the elements are immutable. I'm not sure the second is even making a copy? I can't say I've seen a slice used on the left side before. It almost looks like that's just a reassignment.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, in the second case, the expression `a[:]` on the left-hand side of the assignment **does not make any copy** (shallow or deep) of `a`

It just says that you want to replace the complete slice of `a`, with the values from `[1, 2, 3]`

Only in the 3rd part of your code snippet, `a[:]` results in a copy of `a`. And it will be a **shallow** copy -- not a deep one. But to demonstrate that `a[:]` makes only a shallow copy, you'll have to fill your list `a` with some mutable objects. Currently, you've only filled them with `int` values. For example, you could fill your list `a` with inner lists:

```
a = [ ['a', 'b'], 2] # First element of a is a list, which is a mutable object.
b = a[:]             # b will now have a shallow copy of a, which means that
                     # the first element of a and the first element of b, both refer to
                     # the same object, which is the inner list ['a', 'b']
b[0].append('c')     # Mutate the first element of b.
a                    # You'll find that the change is visible thru list a also.
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a shallow copy. But I think you misunderstand what "shallow" means. Your 3rd example does only illustrate that `a` and `b` are different objects. However, the items they contain are not different objects. You can't see it in this case, since you have numbers, which are immutable anyway.

However, if the items in `a` were *mutable* objects (eg, other lists), modifying them in `a` would also modify them in `b`

```
a = [[]]
b = a[:]
b.append(3) # this does not change a
a[0].append(1) # this changes b
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2]
b=a         #in this case whatever changes we apply to a or b 
             is reflected in both.
a.append(3)
b
[1, 2, 3]
a
[1, 2, 3]
b.append(4)
a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
a=[[]]
b=a[:]      #in this case whatever changes we apply to
            b is reflected only in b and whatever changes are 
            applied in a is only reflected in a.
 b.append(3)
 a[0].append(1)
 print(b)
 [[1], 3]
 a
 [[1]]
 a=[1,2]
 b=a[:]
 b.append(3)
 b
 [1, 2, 3]                #change only in b.
 a
 [1, 2]                   #no change in a
 a.append(4)   
 a
 [1, 2, 4]                #change only in a.
 b
 [1, 2, 3]                #no change in b.
```

Comment: Hope This Helps.